# how to run springboot2.0 on tomcat7?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I write kotlin project with springboot2.0 ,when i want to run on tomcat7 ,but failed.I find some answers on web,and trid,not success.How to do can resolve this probleam?

I tried to set tomcat version to 7.0.58,but failed.

```
allprojects {

    group 'com.nbugs.bridge'
    version '1.0.0'

    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.2.51"
        boot_version = "2.0.5.RELEASE"
        tomcat_embed = "7.0.59"
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}






dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

}
```

not success

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 uses Spring 5.0 which requires Java 8 and a Servlet 3.1 servlet container. Tomcat 7.0 doesn’t support servlet 3.1 and as such won’t work with Spring Boot 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot web comes with Tomcat, if you want to change the version, you can do it by following way:

```
ext['tomcat.version'] = '8.0.36'

dependencies {   
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile group:'org.apache.tomcat', name:'tomcat-juli', version:property('tomcat.version') 
}
```